# Joomla - "Menu Item Type" pop-up is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, joomla3.4

Suddenly - I don't know since when - I can't edit menu item types anymore. When I click the select button, a pop up appears, but it stays empty. It's the same for new menu's and menu items.

Does it seem familiar to anyone? I already searched a lot, but I can't find other people with the same problem.

It seems like the javascript is not loading.

I'm running Joomla 3.4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If JavaScript was broken, I guess you would not see the modal at all.

Increase the error level in Joomla configuration (System -> Global Configuration -> Server -> Error Reporting, and maybe in the modal page you will see a clearer error message).

Comment: I didn't knew this feature of error reporting! It indeed gave an error about one of the extensions (DIVI Image Resizer). Disabling this extension at least gave me back the menu item types! Thanks.

Comment: @CoenSmits happy to hear that! You may want to report the error to the developer of that extension.

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause is the `Header set X-Frame-Options: "deny"` setting in the apache configuration. This causes a `Load denied by X-Frame-Options` error in the browser. Changing the apache configuration to `Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN` fixed it for me.