# Joomla Menu Item Article List Blank

Tags: joomla, menu

I have a Joomla (2.5.4) site which uses menus. Recently I went to add a menu item to an existing menu. When I click on the "Select/Change" button the resulting window shows up, but the list of articles is blank. This also happens when trying to modify an existing item. I not even sure where to start looking on this one. What could be causing this window to not retrieve the list of articles?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31417895/joomla-menu-item-type-pop-up-is-empty

Comment: Also, slightly unrelated, please update to Joomla 2.5.28 as soon as possible, unless you have very very important reasons not to.

Comment: Turning on system debug did not show any errors.

Comment: No turn error reporting on, not system debug.  Server panel, put it on development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site owner agreed to upgrade to the latest version of Joomla and the issue was resolved, which is good news. The bad news is I still do not know what caused the issue in the first place or what part of the upgrade fixed it.